# javascript files bundle cashing problem in with .net6

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, iis-8, bundling-and-minification

I have a .net6 MVC application and i am using WEBOPTIMIZER to bundle my JS Files
,the application is hosted on IIS where i installed NET Core Hosting Bundle
the problem is when i make any changes to my JavaScript files it doesn't reflect on these files on the client browser no matter how many time i clear the cash or even use private mode

it only works when i change the name of the application which is not an acceptable option for the client

I tried clearing the cash after making the changes but there were no effect

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.